# Create node set and pass as a parameter

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Using XSLT 1.0, I'm trying to essentially create a small node set and then pass it as a parameter to a template, something like the following:

```
<xsl:call-template name="widget">
  <xsl:with-param name="flags">
    <items>
      <item>widget.recent-posts.trim-length=100</item>
      <item>widget.recent-posts.how-many=3</item>
      <item>widget.recent-posts.show-excerpt</item>
    </items>
  </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

The idea is that then from within the `widget` template I could write something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$flags/item[1]" />
```

Obviously I get compile errors.. how can I achieve this sort of thing?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**There is a way (non-standard) in XSLT 1.0 to create temporary trees dynamically** and evaluate XPath expressions on them, **however this requires using the `xxx:node-set()` function**.

**Whenever nodes are dynamically created inside the body of an `xsl:variable` or an `xsl:param`, the type of that `xsl:variable` / `xsl:param` is RTF** (Result Tree Fragment) and the W3 XSLT 1.0 Spec. limits severyly the kind of XPath expressions that can be evaluated against an RTF.

**As a workaround, almost every XSLT 1.0 vendor has their own `xxx:node-set()` extension** function that takes an RTF and produces a normal node-set from it.

The namespace to which the `xxx` prefix (or any other prefix you choose) is bound is different for different vendors. For MSXML and the two .NET XSLT processor it is: `"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"`. The EXSLT library uses the namespace: `"http://exslt.org/common"`. This namespace EXSLT is implemented on many XSLT 1.0 processors and it is recommended to use its `xxx:node-set()` extension, if possible.

**Here is a quick example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
  exclude-result-prefixes="ext msxsl"
 >
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vTempRTF">
   <a>
    <b/>
   </a>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:copy-of select="ext:node-set($vTempRTF)/a/*"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, I managed to get around this in the following way:

First add a custom namespace to your stylesheet, e.g. `xmlns:myns="http://my.ns.com"`

Then define the nodeset at the top of the stylesheet:

```
<myns:recent-posts-flags>
    <item>widget.recent-posts.trim-length=100</item>
    <item>widget.recent-posts.how-many=3</item>
    <item>widget.recent-posts.show-excerpt</item>
</myns:recent-posts-flags>
```

Then reference in the following way:

```
<xsl:call-template name="widget">
    <xsl:with-param name="flags" select="document('')/*/myns:recent-posts-flags" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

This works, but it would still be ideal for me to define the node-set within the `<xsl:with-param>` tag itself, as in the first example I gave.. anyone think that would be possible?

Comment: +1 This is FAQ and also in the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#stylesheet-element): `In addition, the xsl:stylesheet element may contain any element not from the XSLT namespace, provided that the expanded-name of the element has a non-null namespace URI. (...) Such elements can provide, for example, information used by extension elements or extension functions, information about what to do with the result tree, information about how to obtain the source tree, metadata about the stylesheet, structured documentation for the stylesheet.`

Comment: You need to define "myns" also, or the transformation will fail. I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873954/namespaces-in-xslt that helped med migure out that adding xmlns:myns="http://localhost" to my xsl:stylesheet-node fixed that issue.

Comment: That's exactly what I said in the second line of the answer.

Comment: Yes. Its just me that reads to badly and googles to fast. >_<

Comment: Hello, did any of you managed to use this approach with PHP? seems like php XSLTProcessor can't cope well with `document('')` invocation...

Comment: Yes, Ibrutti. It works fantastically, especially as a means of defining a set of values to be processed in an `xsl:for-each` tag.