# Namespaces in XSLT

Tags: xslt, namespaces, xslt-2.0

I'm learning how to do custom functions in XSLT. Every example I find seems to declare a custom namespace, e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:mynamespace="http://whatever">
```

What I don't understand is what should go where I currently have 'http://whatever', and what does this do? Can't I use the default xsl namespace to make functions?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#stylesheet-functions

> **Note:**
>
> The prefix must not refer to a
>   [reserved namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-reserved-namespace): [[see ERR
>   XTSE0080](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#err-XTSE0080)]

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-reserved-namespace

> Definition: The XSLT namespace,
>   together with certain other namespaces
>   recognized by an XSLT processor, are
>   classified as reserved namespaces and
>   must be used only as specified in this
>   and related specifications.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#err-XTSE0080

> It is a static error to
>   use a reserved namespace in the name
>   of a named template, a mode, an
>   attribute set, a key, a
>   decimal-format, a variable or
>   parameter, a stylesheet function, a
>   named output definition, or a
>   character map.

Answer (score 2):

If your stylesheet is throwaway code, use anything you like for the namespace for local functions. I sometimes use "http://localhost/", but I've also been known to use "my:functions". If the stylesheet is going to be seen or used by other people and the functions need to be reusable and documented, then think carefully about choosing a namespace that will be globally unique and reflects the design authority for the specification of the functions; most people choose something like http://your.domain.name/ns/purpose, and you might also consider putting a specification of the functions at that location on the web. Another convention, if your function library is closely associated with a particular XML vocabulary, and has the same design authority as that vocabulary, is to put the functions in the same namespace as the elements in that vocabulary.