# Comma separated string parsing XSLT to for-each node

Tags: xslt

I have an input string which has csv values. Eg., 1,2,3
I would need to separate each values and assign to target node in for-each loop.

I got this below template that splits the input string based on delimiter. How can I assign each of the delimited values to the target element in for-each loop.

```
<xsl:template name="output-tokens">
<xsl:param name="list"/>
<xsl:param name="delimiter"/>
<xsl:variable name="newlist">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter)">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($list)"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space($list), $delimiter)"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="first" select="substring-before($newlist, $delimiter)"/>
<xsl:variable name="remaining"
              select="substring-after($newlist, $delimiter)"/>
<xsl:variable name="count" select="position()"/>
<num>
  <xsl:value-of select="$first"/>
</num>
<xsl:if test="$remaining">
  <xsl:call-template name="output-tokens">
    <xsl:with-param name="list" select="$remaining"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter">
      <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
    </xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Input xml:

```
<out1:AvailableDates>
<out1:AvailableDate>15/12/2011,16/12/2011,19/12/2011,20/12/2011,21/12/2011</out1:AvailableDate>
</out1:AvailableDates>
```

Expected Output:

```
<tns:AvailableDates>
<tns:AvailableDate>15/12/2011</tns:AvailableDate>
<tns:AvailableDate>16/12/2011</tns:AvailableDate>
<tns:AvailableDate>120/12/2011</tns:AvailableDate>
</tns:AvailableDates>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Here is a complete and short, true XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:out1="undefined" xmlns:tns="tns:tns"
  exclude-result-prefixes="out1 tns">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="out1:AvailableDate">
  <tns:AvailableDates>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </tns:AvailableDates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="split">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="pItemElementName" select="'tns:AvailableDate'"/>
  <xsl:param name="pItemElementNamespace" select="'tns:tns'"/>

    <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) > 0">
     <xsl:variable name="vNextItem" select=
      "substring-before(concat($pText, ','), ',')"/>

      <xsl:element name="{$pItemElementName}"
                   namespace="{$pItemElementNamespace}">
       <xsl:value-of select="$vNextItem"/>
      </xsl:element>

      <xsl:call-template name="split">
        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
                       "substring-after($pText, ',')"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pItemElementName" select="$pItemElementName"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pItemElementNamespace" select="$pItemElementNamespace"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be made well-formed):

```
<out1:AvailableDates xmlns:out1="undefined">
    <out1:AvailableDate>15/12/2011,16/12/2011,19/12/2011,20/12/2011,21/12/2011</out1:AvailableDate>
</out1:AvailableDates>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<tns:AvailableDates xmlns:tns="tns:tns">
   <tns:AvailableDate>15/12/2011</tns:AvailableDate>
   <tns:AvailableDate>16/12/2011</tns:AvailableDate>
   <tns:AvailableDate>19/12/2011</tns:AvailableDate>
   <tns:AvailableDate>20/12/2011</tns:AvailableDate>
   <tns:AvailableDate>21/12/2011</tns:AvailableDate>
</tns:AvailableDates>
```

Comment: @Arun: I am glad my answer was useful. Could you, please, mark the answer as accepted (click on the check-mark next to the answer)? This is the officially established way of expressing gratitude at SO.

Comment: Definitly. In my XSL I am getting the mesage: <xsl:template match="/"> and <xsl:template name="..."> are the only permitted <template> elements in the XSL. When I use <xsl:template match="/out1:Response/out1:AvailableDates/out1:AvailableDate">

Comment: @Arun: THis message means that in your `xsl:template` instruction you have used an attribute other than `match` or `name`. Find what other attribute you have used and remove it.

Answer (score 12):

With XSLT 2.0 you can use `tokenize(string, separator)` function instead of named template.

And this xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tns="http://tnsnamespace">

    <xsl:template match="AvailableDate">
        <tns:AvailableDates>
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(current(), ',')">
                <tns:AvailableDate>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </tns:AvailableDate>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tns:AvailableDates>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:AvailableDates xmlns:tns="http://tnsnamespace">
    <tns:AvailableDate>15/12/2011</tns:AvailableDate>
    <tns:AvailableDate>16/12/2011</tns:AvailableDate>
    <tns:AvailableDate>19/12/2011</tns:AvailableDate>
    <tns:AvailableDate>20/12/2011</tns:AvailableDate>
    <tns:AvailableDate>21/12/2011</tns:AvailableDate>
</tns:AvailableDates>
```

**Update**:

With Xslt 2.0 processor under backward compatibility mode following template gives the same result:

```
<xsl:template match="AvailableDate">
    <tns:AvailableDates>
        <xsl:variable name="myValue">
            <xsl:call-template name="output-tokens">
                <xsl:with-param name="list" select="."/>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:for-each select="$myValue/node()">
            <tns:AvailableDate>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </tns:AvailableDate>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tns:AvailableDates>
</xsl:template>
```

For **Xslt 1.0** - it is not possible simple (with standard functions) access to nodes via variable - see @Dimitre Novatchev answer [XSLT 1.0 - Create node set and pass as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880499/xslt-1-0-create-node-set-and-pass-as-a-parameter)

For this purpose XSLT 1.0 processors contains extension function: `node-set(...)`

For Saxon 6.5 `node-set()` function is defined in `http://icl.com/saxon` namespace

So in the case of XSLT 1.0 processors solution would be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:out1="http://out1namespace"
    xmlns:tns="http://tnsnamespace"
    exclude-result-prefixes="out1 exslt">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="out1:AvailableDate">
        <tns:AvailableDates>
            <xsl:variable name="myValue">
                <xsl:call-template name="output-tokens">
                    <xsl:with-param name="list" select="."/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($myValue)/node()">
                <tns:AvailableDate>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </tns:AvailableDate>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tns:AvailableDates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="output-tokens">
        <xsl:param name="list"/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter"/>
        <xsl:variable name="newlist">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($list)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space($list), $delimiter)"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="first" select="substring-before($newlist, $delimiter)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="remaining"
            select="substring-after($newlist, $delimiter)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="count" select="position()"/>
        <num>
            <xsl:value-of select="$first"/>
        </num>
        <xsl:if test="$remaining">
            <xsl:call-template name="output-tokens">
                <xsl:with-param name="list" select="$remaining"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks @Dimitre Novatchev to correct me and his answer about accessing node sets from variable.

Comment: Thank very much. I am using BPEL 10g. Its having xslt version 1.0. What is possible in it?

Comment: I've updated my answer for Xslt-1.0 - it uses your *output-tokens* named template

Comment: @Vitaliy: Please, do run your XSLT 1.0 solution with any XSLT 1.0 (compliant) processor and see that this produces an error. In XSLT 1.0 there are a very limited set of operations that are allowed on an RTF (Result Tree Fragment). Please, correct.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev - yes, I see it doesn't work with Saxon 6.5.5 (only works when I added version="1.1"), but works with Saxon 9.3 under backward compatibility mode.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev - fixed with node-set() extension function

Comment: @Vitaliy: Good. I will upvote this answer if you edit it and use the EXSLT namespace (which is supported by the majority of existing XSLT 1.0 processor), instead of the proprietory Saxon namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer this variant based on custom extension functions. The method is compact and clean, and works fine in XSLT 1.0 (at least with XALAN 2.7 as embedded in any recent JVM).

1) declare a class with a static method returning a org.w3c.dom.Node

```
package com.reverseXSL.util;

import org.w3c.dom.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

public class XslTools {

  public static Node splitToNodes(String input, String regex) throws Exception {
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    Element item, list = doc.createElement("List");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
      item = doc.createElement("Item");
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
      for (int i=1; i<=m.groupCount(); ++i) if (m.start(i)>=0) sb.append(m.group(i));
      Text txt = doc.createTextNode(sb.toString());
      item.appendChild(txt);
      list.appendChild(item);
    }
    return list; 
  }

}
```

This function splits an input string on a regex pattern and creates a document fragment of the kind <list><Item>A</Item><Item>B</Item><Item>C</Item></List>. 
The regex is matched in sequence, each match yielding an Item element whose value is composed from the capturing groups (some possibly empty) inside each regex match. This allows to get rid from delimiters and other syntax chars.

For instance, to split a comma-separated list like `" A, B ,, C"`, skip empty values, and trim extra spaces (hence get the above Node list), use a regex like `'\s*([^,]+?)\s*(?:,|$)'` - a mind twisting one! If instead you want to split the input text by a fixed size (here 10 chars) with the last Item taking whatever remains, use a regex like `'(.{10}|.+)'` - love it!

You can then use the function in XSLT 1.0 as follows (quite compact!):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:var="com.reverseXSL.util.XslTools" extension-element-prefixes="var" ...
...
<xsl:template ...
  ...
  <xsl:for-each select="var:splitToNodes(Detail/CsvText,'\s*([^,]+?)\s*(?:,|$)')/Item">
    <Loop><xsl:value-of select="."/></Loop>
  </xsl:for-each>
...
```

Executed on a template match yielding the input fragment `<Detail><CsvText>a, b ,c </CsvText></Detail>` you'll generate `<Loop>a</Loop><Loop>b</Loop><Loop>c</Loop>`

The trick is not forgetting to follow the function call that generates the Node/Item by the XPath "/Item" (or "/*") as you shall note, so that a Node sequence is returned into the for-each loop.

Comment: If you're working with Xalan, then you can use the EXSLT `str:tokenize()` extension function which Xalan supports, instead of having to write your own. But XSLT 1.0 does not necessarily mean you're using Xalan or Java.