# Transform an element into multiple nested elements based on its attribute value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have some HTML containing styled spans like these:

```
<p><span class="foo">unstyled span</span></p>
<p><span style="font-style: italic;">italic</span></p>
<p><span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">bold italic</span></p>
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;">underline italic bold</span></p>
```

Spans are also used there to set font and background color and few more things. Basically I have to replace `span` tags with `em`, `strong`, etc. where possible, keep some styles and remove everything else (unneeded styles and classes). For the above input, the desired output is:

```
<p>unstyled span</p>
<p><em>italic</em></p>
<p><em><strong>bold italic</strong></em></p>
<p><em><strong><span style="text-decoration: underline;">underline italic bold</span></strong></em></p>
```

With my very limited XSLT skills I was able to write the following transformation that does the job but looks ugly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="span">
    <xsl:call-template name="startStyleTests" select="." />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="startStyleTests">
    <xsl:call-template name="testItalic" select="." />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="testItalic">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains(./@style, 'italic')">
        <xsl:element name="em"><xsl:call-template name="testBold" select="." /></xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise><xsl:call-template name="testBold" select="." /></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="testBold">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains(./@style, 'bold')">
        <xsl:element name="strong"><xsl:call-template name="testUnderline" select="." /></xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise><xsl:call-template name="testUnderline" select="." /></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="testUnderline">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains(./@style, 'underline')">
        <xsl:element name="span">
          <xsl:attribute name="style">text-decoration: underline;</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:call-template name="endStyleTests" select="." />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise><xsl:call-template name="endStyleTests" select="." /></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="endStyleTests">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

(a few "testSomething" templates removed for readability)

How should it really be done with XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is create a variable that holds a "mapping" of the styles to elements that you want

```
<xsl:variable name="styles">
   <style match="italic" element="em" />
   <style match="bold" element="strong" />
   <style match="underline" element="span" style="text-decoration: underline;" />
</xsl:variable>
```

Then, rather than have separate templates for each style mapping, you can have one template, that recursively checks each of the mappings in turn.

Note that in XSLT 1.0 the `styles` variable actually contains what is known as a "Result Tree Fragment", so you will need an extension function to process them as nodes.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
               xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
               exclude-result-prefixes="exslt">

  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="styles">
    <style match="italic" element="em" />
    <style match="bold" element="strong" />
    <style match="underline" element="span" style="text-decoration: underline;" />
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="span">
    <xsl:call-template name="startStyleTests" /> 
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="startStyleTests">
    <xsl:param name="styleNumber" select="1" />
    <xsl:variable name="style" select="exslt:node-set($styles)/style[position() = $styleNumber]" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($style)">
          <xsl:call-template name="endStyleTests" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="contains(@style, $style/@match)">
        <xsl:element name="{$style/@element}">
         <xsl:if test="$style/@style">
           <xsl:attribute name="style">
             <xsl:value-of select="$style/@style" />
           </xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:call-template name="startStyleTests">
            <xsl:with-param name="styleNumber" select="$styleNumber + 1" />
         </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:call-template name="startStyleTests">
          <xsl:with-param name="styleNumber" select="$styleNumber + 1" />
       </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="endStyleTests">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Alternatively, you could put the style mappings in a separate XML document, and then use the `document()` function to access it. That would not need an extension function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the `document()` tip, Tim.

I have also found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3880709/7763334) on using a node set as a parameter and followed it to create a version that does not need an extension and keeps style mappings in the same document.