# how to transform again the XML output obtained from XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Is there any way that I can use XSLT to process again(2nd time) the XML that is obtained during the first processing?

To be more clear,

I got the following output, while the transformation is going on,

```
<processPrototypes>
     <orderPrecedenceSpec origin="xxx"
                          target="yyy"
                          orderType="directOrder"/>
     <orderPrecedenceSpec origin="abc"
                          target="lmn"
                          orderType="directOrder"/>
     <orderPrecedenceSpec origin="xxx"
                          target="yyy"
                          orderType="directOrder"/>
     <orderPrecedenceSpec origin="abc"
                          target="lmn"
                          orderType="directOrder"/>
  </processPrototypes>
```

In my xslt, the line/template that does this part is,

```
   <processPrototypes>

        <xsl:call-template name="help">
        </xsl:call-template>

    </processPrototypes>

    What to do in the next line here ? to modify the output created by the above template ?
```

Now my question is can I be able to process the "processPrototypes" output to remove the duplication there ? in the same xslt file just in the next line after calling the template ?

So that after processing it again, my final output should look like (without duplication),

```
     <processPrototypes>
         <orderPrecedenceSpec origin="xxx"
                              target="yyy"
                              orderType="directOrder"/>
         <orderPrecedenceSpec origin="abc"
                              target="lmn"
                              orderType="directOrder"/>
      </processPrototypes>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSLT 1.0 - Create node set and pass as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880499/xslt-1-0-create-node-set-and-pass-as-a-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your XSLT processor supports some variant of the [`node-set()` function](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html), you can do something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="prototypes">
  <processPrototypes>
    <xsl:call-template name="help" />
  </processPrototypes>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($prototypes)" />
```

When you create a variable that contains markup or XSLT processing like `apply-templates`, etc., like the `prototypes` variable above, this creates a *node fragment*, which cannot be accessed the way you would access a node-set. The `node-set()` function converts that node fragment into a node-set so that you can perform XSLT processing on it, traverse it with XPath, and so on. I believe this function is available in a handful of major XSLT processors.

Comment: @Legolas Isn't Saxon an XSLT 3.0 processor? Your question is tagged with XSLT 1.0.

Comment: I am using saxon 9,8HE online editor just to see quick outputs...But actually I will be using only xslt 1.0 (xalan)

Comment: @Legolas The `node-set` function does not exist in Saxon because Saxon is an XSLT 3.0 (or 2.0) processor and `node-set` would be irrelevant there. What environment are you executing your xalan in? According to the page I linked to, the namespace to use would differ depending on whether you're using xalan-J or xalan-C.

Comment: I am using xalan-J 2.7.1... but it works with saxon as well... https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9s/8